# Functionality to add a "next page" and "previous page" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I wrote this json file that contains the information for a table.

In my table I want to only show up to 5 rows of the data in the file.

I want the user to click next and it shows the next 5 objects in the data.
I can't seem to find a solution or method I can use myself. I am using NodeJS and ejs as my view engine.

```
  <tbody>
    <% data.s_history.forEach((record) => { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=record.date%>
          <span style="display: block;font-size:10pt;"><%=record.time%></span>
      </td>


      <td>
        <% record.course.forEach((course) => { %>
        <%=course.subject%>
          <span style="display:block;font-size: 10pt;"><%=course.class%></span>
        <% }) %>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="image" class="web_camera" src="/img/camera.png">
      </td>

      <td>
        <% record.session.forEach((session) => { %>
          <span><%=session.date%></span><img src="<%=session.course_type%>"></img>
          <p><%=session.details%></span>
        <% }) %>
      </td>

      <td>
        <% record.instructor.forEach((teacher) => {%>
          <img rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<%=teacher.name%>" src="<%=teacher.img%>"></img>
        <% }) %>
      </td>

      <td>
        <% record.student.forEach((person) => { %>
          <img rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<%=person.name%>" src="<%=person.img%>">
        <% }) %>
      </td>

      <td>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MessageModal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send Message" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/message.png"></img></button>
        <button rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add Course" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/plus-course-record.png"></img></button>
        <a href='/student_grading' rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Grading & Feedback"  class="record_icons"><img src="/img/nike.png"></img></a>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ChangeModal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Change Course" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/change.png"></img></button>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelModal" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel Course" class="record_icons"><img src="/img/x.png"></img></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
```

See I want to only loop through a certain amount of data. Then when next or previous is clicked it passes the next set.

Comment: Firstly do you want with page reload or without page reload(with ajax)?

Comment: Without page reload

Answer (score 0):

Simple build a API that provides the client the table details. The EJS page will have a blank table and will initiate a AJAX request to the API on page load. You can even show a loader for rich user experience. By this way your page will load faster than the current implementation.